# Can't assign wide char into wide char field.

Tags: c, widechar

I have been given this school project. I have to alphabetically sort list of items by Czech rules. Before I dig deeper, I have decided to test it on a 16 by 16 matrix so I did this:

```
typedef struct {    
wint_t **field;
}LIST;

...

setlocale(LC_CTYPE,NULL);

....

list->field=(wint_t **)malloc(16*sizeof(wint_t *));
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)  
list->field[i]=(wint_t *)malloc(16*sizeof(wint_t));
```

In another function I am trying to assign a char. Like this:

```
sorted->field[15][15] = L'C';
wprintf(L"%c\n",sorted->field[15][15]);
```

Everything is fine. Char is printed. But when I try to change it to

```
sorted->field[15][15] = L'Č';
```

It says: Extraneous characters in wide character constant ignored. (Xcode) And the printing part is skipped. The main.c file is in UTF-8. If I try to print this:

```
printf("ěščřžýááíé\n");
```

It prints it out as written. I am not sure if I should allocate mem using wint_t or wchar_t or if I am doing it right. I tested it with both but none of them works.

Comment: Duplicate of [Using Wide Character Constants with clang Gets "extraneous characters in wide character constant ignored" Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343553/using-wide-character-constants-with-clang-gets-extraneous-characters-in-wide-ch) - the important part is that clang doesn't support this behaviour yet.  Try GCC if you really need it.  `printf()` works because the compiler doesn't have to care about what bytes are in the string.  When your terminal sees that sequence *it* does the right thing.

Comment: @CarlNorum Well I just tried it with gcc and simpler code and it didn't print anything. http://pastebin.com/SZmTekYW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clang seems to support entering arbitrary byte sequences into to wide strings with the `\x` notation:

```
wchar_t c = L'\x2126';
```

This compiles without notice.

*Edit:* Adapting what I find on [wikipedia about wide characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character), the following works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t myChar1 = L'\x2126';
    wchar_t myChar2 = 0x2126;  // hexadecimal encoding of char Ω using UTF-16
    wprintf(L"This is char: %lc \n",myChar1);
    wprintf(L"This is char: %lc \n",myChar2);
}
```

and prints nice `Ω` characters in my terminal. Make sure that your teminal is able to interpret utf-8 characters.

Comment: So if I understand it right Xcode (on Lion) uses clang. Support for GCC was dropped with the Lion update. But the problem is, if I try to compile it using terminal and GCC (http://pastebin.com/SZmTekYW). It does not print anything. Even if I use \x2118.

Comment: @rojcyk perhaps this was just the wrong character, please see my edit.